# Mac text to speech reading entire html page instead of selected text

Tags: macos, mac

I have recently started using Mac text to speech its hadny.

I use it to read articles online/blogs. Though i have found that it used to speak only selected text however now it start reading entire page and all links etc...

Few more things i found are as follows,

- When i select text and select speak explicitly from menu of browser it reads selected text correctly
- But when i select text and click option + esc key it reads entire page from all the way to menu and left navigator text etc

I have faced above behaviour for [Wikipedia Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) and some other as well.

I checked speak selected text option is checked in settings.
[image]

Has anyone faced this issue and any idea why it does it like this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After so many trials and error i could figure out that speak selected text in browser only works with Mac Safari and not for other browsers.

So i think that answer the question and might help someone else with the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I use option+esc to read the selection all the time in Firefox on Lion...